# Why does some Ruby code run twice as fast on a 2.53GHz than on a 2.2GHz Core 2 Duo processor?

Tags: ruby, performance

(This question attempts to find out why the running of a program can be different on different processors, so it is related to the performance aspect of programming.)

The following program will take 3.6 seconds to run on a Macbook that has 2.2GHz Core 2 Duo, and 1.8 seconds to run on a Macbook Pro that has 2.53GHz Core 2 Duo.  Why is that?

That's a bit weird... why doubling the speed when the CPU is only 15% faster in clock speed?  I double checked the CPU meter to make sure none of the 2 cores are in 100% usage (so as to see the CPU is not busy running something else).  Could it be because one is Mac OS X Leopard and one is Mac OS X Snow Leopard (64 bit)?  Both are running Ruby 1.9.2.

```
p RUBY_VERSION
p RUBY_DESCRIPTION if defined? RUBY_DESCRIPTION
n = 9_999_999
p n

t = 0; 1.upto(n) {|i| t += i if i%3==0 || i%5==0}; p t
```

**The following are just output of the program:**

On 2.2GHz Core 2 Duo: (**Update:** Macbook identifier: MacBook3,1, therefore probably is Intel Core 2 Duo (T7300/T7500))

```
$ time ruby 1.rb
"1.9.2"
"ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [i386-darwin9.8.0]"
9999999
23333331666668

real  0m3.784s
user  0m3.751s
sys  0m0.021s
```

2.53GHz Intel Core 2 Duo:  (**Update:** Macbook identifier: MacBookPro5,4, therefore probably is Intel Core 2 Duo Penryn with 3 MB on-chip L2 cache)

```
$ time ruby 1.rb
"1.9.2"
"ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [x86_64-darwin10.4.0]"
9999999
23333331666668

real  0m1.893s
user  0m1.809s
sys  0m0.012s
```

Test run on Windows 7:

```
time_start = Time.now

p RUBY_VERSION
p RUBY_DESCRIPTION if defined? RUBY_DESCRIPTION

n = 9_999_999
p n

t = 0; 1.upto(n) {|i| t += i if i%3==0 || i%5==0}; p t

print "Took #{Time.now - time_start} seconds to run\n"
```

Intel Q6600 Quad Core 2.4GHz running Windows 7, 64-bit:

```
C:\> ruby try.rb
"1.9.2"
"ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18) [i386-mingw32]"
9999999
23333331666668
Took 3.248186 seconds to run
```

Intel 920 i7 2.67GHz running Windows 7, 64-bit:

```
C:\> ruby try.rb
"1.9.2"
"ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18) [i386-mingw32]"
9999999
23333331666668
Took 2.044117 seconds to run
```

It is also strange why an i7 with 2.67GHz is slower than a 2.53GHz Core 2 Duo.

Comment: Can you post the exact model numbers for the Core2 CPUs?

Comment: How do I do that for Macbook?  The "More Info..." won't show it either...

Comment: Do the processors have the same amount of cache memory ? Are you sure one of them arn't stuck in some power saving mode ?

Comment: I am not a linux guru, but try the command 'cat /proc/cpuinfo' on command line.

Comment: @Klinky sorry, no /proc folder on the Mac

Comment: Try some of the commands listed here: http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=43422

Comment: by the way, I found a way to tell the CPU model: in the "About this Mac", there is a "Model Identifier", using it, the processor's model can be found in Wikipedia. (and I update the post to add the model numbers there)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suspect that ruby is switching to a arbitrary-precision integer implementation
later on the 64 bit os.

Quoting the Fixnum ruby doc:

> A Fixnum holds Integer values that can
>   be represented in a *native machine
>   word* (minus 1 bit). If any operation
>   on a Fixnum exceeds this range, the
>   value is automatically converted to a
>   Bignum.

Here, a native machine word is technically 64 bit, but the interpreter is compiled to run on 32 bit processors.

Comment: I think this is the most likely explanation.  Well spotted.

Comment: Yes your Test is exceeding the 32 Bit Number range, so Ruby has to Switch to the (Slow) Bignum representation when using the 32 Bit Compiler binaries

Comment: that's true, on Leopard, the final answer `23333331666668.class` gave `Bignum` while on Snow Leopard, it is `Fixnum`.  I also tried modifying the program, so that it loops `10000` times to add the total, and iterate this for 1000 times, and on Snow Leopard, it took 1.8 seconds, and Leopard, 2.6 seconds (slower CPU too), but more inline with the CPU speed difference.

Answer (score 2):

> *why doubling the speed when the CPU is only 15% faster in clock speed?*

Quite simply because the performance of computers is determined not solely by CPU clock speed.

Other things to consider are:

- CPU architectures, including e.g. the number of cores on a CPU, or the general ability to run multiple instructions in parallel
- other clock speeds in the system (memory, FSB)
- CPU cache sizes
- installed memory chips (some are faster than others)
- additionally installed hardware (might slow down the system through hardware interruptions)
- different operating systems
- 32-bit vs. 64-bit systems

I'm sure there's a lot more things to add to the above list. I won't elaborate further on the point, but if anyone feels like it, please, feel free to add to the above list.

Comment: I know it doesn't depend solely on the clock speed.  But why the doubling?  What are some specific reasons?

Comment: saw the things you added in the edit.  But this programs runs faster on a dual core than on a quad core, memory bus is not so important, as I see that with Ruby, it is merely using 3MB of RAM, and the main loop is probably using less than a few kb, so the L1 cache should be well above the requirement.

Comment: @動靜能量, my main point here was not so much finding the exact or likeliest cause of the speed difference -- I don't know enough about your test machines for that. Rather I'm suggesting that these days, there are so many factors playing into performance that direct comparisons are hardly ever easy, or even meaningful, especially so for one single program. Also, it's easy to then get caught up with optimizing your code towards one particular machine... and your code will end up running slower on another. -- That all being said, I find such a big speed difference very interesting, too.

Answer (score 2):

In out CI environment we have a lot of "pizza box" computers that are supposed to be identical. They have the same hardware, were installed at the same time, and should be generally identical. They're even placed in "thermally equivalent" locations. They're not identical, and the variation can be quite stunning.

The only conclusion I have come up with is different binnings of CPU will have different thresholds for thermal stepping; some of the "best" chips hold up better. I also suspect other "minor" hardware faults/variations to be playing a role here. Maybe the slow boxes have slightly different components that play less well together ?

There are tools out there that will show you if your CPU is throttling for thermal reasons.

Comment: Continious Integration; build system

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much Ruby, but your code doesn't look to be multithreaded, if that's the case it's not going to take advantage of multiple cores. There can also be large differences between two CPU models. You have smaller process sizes, larger caches, better SIMD instructions sets, faster memory access, etc... Compiler & OS differences can cause large swings in performance between Windows & Linux, this can also be said for x86 vs x64. Plus Core i7s support HyperThreading which in some cases makes a single threaded app slower.

Just as an example, if that 2.2Ghz CPU is an Intel Core2 E4500 it has the following specs:

- Clock: 2.2Ghz
- L2 Cache: 2MB
- FSB: 800MT/sec
- Process Size: 65nm

vs a T9400 which is likely in your MacBook Pro

- Clock: 2.53Ghz
- L2 Cache: 6MB
- FSB: 1066MT/sec
- Process Size: 45nm

Plus you're running it on an x64 build of Darwin. All those things could definitely add up to inflating a trivial little script into executing much faster.

Answer (score 1):

didn't read the code, But.. It is really hard to test on 2 different computers.
You need exactly the same os, same processes, same amount of memory.

If you change the processor family (i7, core2due, P4, P4-D) - the processor frequency says nothing on each processor abilities against another family. you can only compare in the same family (a newer processor might invest cycles in core management rather in computation for example)